# Explain how typecasting works at the bit level from int to short in C

Tags: c, math, logic, bit-manipulation, bit

If the binary representation of 2^31-1 is 01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111, what happens to that binary number when typecast to short?  This is assuming an int is 4 bytes, and a short is 2 bytes.

I wrote a test program, and the output is -1 when typecast to short.  Is this correct?  Does this mean that typecast to short just chopped off the 16 most-significant bits, leaving 11111111 11111111 (signed 2's complement)?

**CODE**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
        int x = sizeof(int);
        int y = sizeof(short);
        printf("%d, %d",x,y);

        int a = 2147483647;
        short b = (short)a;

        printf("\nad: %d",(int)a);
        printf("\nax: %x",(int)a);
        printf("\nau: %u",(int)a);

        printf("\nbd: %d",(int)b);
        printf("\nbx: %x",(int)b);
        printf("\nbu: %u",(int)b);
        printf("\n");
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
4, 2
ad: 2147483647
ax: 7fffffff
au: 2147483647
bd: -1
bx: ffffffff
bu: 4294967295
```

Comment: Nit: It's just called "casting". "Typecasting" is when you see the same actor in the same type of role in TV or films.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you assign an `int` to a `short`, if the value cannot be represented in the range of `short`( [-2^15, 2^15 - 1], in 2's complement), the result is implementation-defined.

**6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers**

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged. Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned... Otherwise, the
>   new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either
>   the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined
>   signal is raised.

As to "implementation-defined", it means that the behavior depends on the compiler, architecture, etc. Concretely, one possible result, as you may already see, is that high bits are simply discarded. This results in `11111111 11111111` in this case.

The other possible result, is that it's "rounded" down to the maximize value in the range. That is `01111111 11111111` in this case. But I can't memorize which implementation act like this.

But either way, don't rely on that.

Comment: Will you please clarify what you mean by "implementation defined"

Comment: @JonSmith It means that an implementation (compiler, architecture, ...) can decide what it does.

Comment: @JonSmith he basically means that each implementation will be different in many terms which will define the answer to this question. Different in terms like endianess or representation of int and short

Answer (score 5):

Any integer in C or any other language is stored in form of some bytes (4 bytes in C, if you use 32-bit C compiler, usually size of `int` depends on Compiler), when you typecast it to `short` and read from memory or assign to any variable, only lower 2 bytes are read or assigned since `short` directs the compiler to read the value as a `short int`.

In your case the integer is `01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` in binary, therefore, when typecasting to `short` it is read as `11111111 11111111` (lower 2 bytes) which is binary representation in 16 bits for `-1` (of course if its `signed short`, which is by default).

What I mean to say is, Suppose you have an `int a = 0x7fffffff` stored at address say `1234`, then the memory representation of `a` will be:

```
 Memory Address:  1237     1236     1235     1234  
 Value:         01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

When you read it as `short`, Only the lower 2 bytes (Addresses 1235 and 1234) are read.
Now reading them as `short` (or signed short) means you want the MSB of the number to be **treated by compiler** as Sign Bit. Since `Sign bit = 1` means it is a negative number, and if you know the 2's Complement Number Format (which is used by C compiler to represent integers) then the number `11111111 11111111` in binary is equal to `-1` in decimal.

Also when you use `%u` or printing the `short int` value, then it is treated as `unsigned`, the MSB contributes (this time) to the magnitude, not a sign bit.

One more thing I would like to add: Typecasting from `short` to `int`.
Whenever you typecast a `short` to `int` as you did in:

```
short b = (short)a;
printf("\nbu: %u",(int)b);
```

the **sign bit** is filled in all the extra higher bits, therefore `11111111 11111111` becomes `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` which is `4294967295` in **unsigned decimal**.

If you try typecasting `01111111 11111111` instead of `11111111 11111111` then it would have been promoted as `00000000 00000000 01111111 11111111` since sign bit is `0`.

Hope you understood my explanation.

Comment: @JonSmith Apparently, yes, in your particular case.

Comment: @H2CO3 : Thanks for pointing that out!! I have worked on 16-bit compiler, even then I did that mistake, my bad!! Now I have corrected it.